# How to redirect according to radio button value in Flask?

Tags: python, html, redirect, flask, radio-button

I'm very new to Flask and I would like to do the following:

1. In my index.html there are two radio buttons and a submit button:

> ```
> <form action="{{ url_for('click') }}" method="POST">    
>     <div class="half">
>         <input type="radio" name="option" value="a" />           
>     </div>
>     <div class="half">
>         <input type="radio" name="option" value="b" />           
>     </div>
>         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
> ```

2. When click submit button, the page should be redirect to another page according to selected radio button value, i.e. "a.html".
3. I'm stuck with the python code here:

> ```
> @app.route('/')
> def home():
>     return render_template('index.html')
>
> @app.route('/<selectedValue>', methods=['POST'])
> def click():
>     selectedValue = request.form['option']
>     return redirect(url_for(selectedValue + '.html'))
> ```

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a function to handle rendering each page you might redirect to?  What's the error you're receiving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't working because when pressing the submit button you will send a post request to your target which is defined by the `action` attribute in your template. However the defined endpoint expects a `selectedValue` parameter which changes depending on your choice. The `url_for()` function you use in your template can't provide that because it is rendered to pure HTML when the template is sent to the client, meaning before a choice has been made.

Try a different approach:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectedValue = request.form['option']
        return redirect(url_for('click', selectedValue=selectedValue))
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/<selectedValue>')
def click(selectedValue):
    return render_template(selectedValue)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)
```

This way you will send the `POST` request to your `home` endpoint and use the `request` object to get your `option` value. Then you will call a redirect function providing providing the `selectedValue`.

**NOTE:** I would recommend using a separate endpoint function for each template you're using.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! however I tried your code and got error: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'click'. Did you forget to specify values ['selectedValue']?

Comment: You have to change `<form action="{{ url_for('click') }}" method="POST">` to `<form method="POST">` in your template.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!